# a periodic problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is exist a third order linear homogeneous differential equation with periodic solutions (for example $y'''+y'=0$). My question is if T is a positive number is there exist a third order linear homogeneous  differential equation  whose every solution is periodic with period T?

Comment: Just $y'''+T^2y'=0$.

Comment: @MartinR I think you mean $y''' + (4 \pi^2/T^2) y' = 0$.  But also $y''' + (4 n^2 \pi^2/T^2) y' = 0$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant :)

Comment: Right thank you!!